# Java increment an integer within a loop

Tags: java, while-loop, integer, increment

My assignment is to read text files that contain combinations for a family with possible outcome of children. `GG = two girls`, `GB` and `BG = one boy one girl`, `BB = two boys`. I am supposed to find the sample's size, and then print ratios of each of the 3 possible outcomes.
I can't seem to get my variables to increment throughout the loop, they come up as 0 every time. I checked the debugger and it shows that each file is being read correctly but the increments aren't working for some reason.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Family
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
  String token = "";
  int girlGirl = 0;
  int boyBoy = 0;
  int girlBoy = 0;
  int sampleSize = 0;
  File fileName = new File("test2.txt");
  Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);

  //read file and get data
  while (inFile.hasNext())
  {
     token = inFile.next();
     if(token == "GG")
     {
         girlGirl++;
         sampleSize++;
     }
     else if(token == "BB")
     {
         boyBoy++;
         sampleSize++;
     }
     else if(token == "GB")
     {
         girlBoy++;
         sampleSize++;
     }
     else if(token == "BG")
     {
         girlBoy++;
         sampleSize++;
     }
  }
  inFile.close();

  int percentBoyBoy = (boyBoy / sampleSize) * 100;
  int percentGirlGirl = (girlGirl / sampleSize) * 100;
  int percentGirlBoy = (girlBoy / sampleSize) * 100;
  //print results of sample
  System.out.println("Sample Size: " + sampleSize);
  System.out.println("Two Boys: " + percentBoyBoy  + "%");
  System.out.println("One Boy One Girl: " + percentGirlBoy  + "%");
  System.out.println("Two Girls: " + percentGirlGirl  + "%");
}//end of main method
}//end of class
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use

```
token.equals("GG");
```

instead of

```
token == "GG"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the division by sampleSize.
sampleSize is an integer larger than any of the "boyBoy" or whatever variables.
Dividing two integers as in "(boyBoy / sampleSize)" will then lead to result 0, since integer divisions lead to integer results and dividing, say (10/100) in integer terms is 0, (110/100) would be 1, etc.
Thus, better do:
 double percentGirlBoy = (girlBoy / ((double)sampleSize)) * 100d

Answer (score 0):

You have to use overridden equals method in String class where you have to pass an object as a parameter. Like this

token.equals("BB");

Here it will compare your content and if you are using Equalto ( == ) Operator , it simply compare the reference value of both String reference and hence it always come **false** and hence " samplesize" will never increment , remain as 0 which is responsible for throwing " **ArithmeticException: / by zero "**.